# Vagrant synced folder

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm studying how Vagrant works, actually I'm reading official docs. The first problem I met is with synced folders. As it's stated in https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/synced_folders.html. I create just a simple text file on a virtual machine in /vagrant directory but when I exit VM I don't see this file in directory with Vagrantfile. Is there any extra configuration required?

My Vagrantfile is as simple as it's possible:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = 2

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
end
```

Comment: Were you able to see the Vagrantfile from within the VM?  There isn't any extra config required, this should *just work™*

Comment: No, I don't see Vagrantfile from VM.

Comment: Looks like folder sharing doesn't work at all, then.  Weird. Which OS are you running on the host machine?

Comment: On my machine I  use Ubuntu 14.04 and on VM Ubuntu 12.04. Should both systems be the same?

Comment: No, that shouldn't matter.  Try running `vagrant reload`.  Any error messages showing up?

Comment: With vagrant reload it works only in one way - I can see files created on VM on my local machine but not in the opposite way.

Comment: I retract my previous comment.  The guest additions may be out of sync as is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18951461/2425163).

Comment: As stated [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html), can you try to enable vagrant debug ? `set VAGRANT_LOG=debug` and then `vagrant up` ?
Also, is the sync working if you explicitly active it ? Do it by adding `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"` to your Vagrantfile

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Guest additions? And if use virtualbox 4.3.10 , you may receive error.(about vboxsf).I created own machine and i try following steps and work.
this page helpful,it shows error on the bottom https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2014/12/19/how-to-create-a-custom-vagrant-box/

Comment: The image is *the* reference image for vagrant.  It has the guest additions installed.  Building one's own box won't help here.

Comment: I'm using virtualbox 4.3.34 and I'm not receiving any errors, even no warnings. And I don't have Guest addition :) what Guest addition does?

Comment: @hebius Guest additions are optimizations to be run on the guest.  They improve performance (and slightly reduce security, as the guest is "less separate" from the host.  Shouldn't matter most of the time).

Comment: virtualbox insert guest additions. would you try  "config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant" https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html